# Как сделать чтобы текст между символов менял цвет

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть код:

```
<div class=“text”>__text__</div>
```

И я хочу чтобы текст между нижними подчеркиваниями был желтого цвета

Answer (score 1):

а в лоб решение не устраивает?

```css
.text span {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='text'>__<span>text</span>__</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

При помощи css вы распознать подобный паттерн не сможете, вам необходимо при помощи js извлекать значение в div'е, парсить, разбивать на подстроки и реплейсить его на несколько тэгов (конечно если вы не можете это сделать сразу при формировании разметки), типа:

```html
<div class="outer">
  __
  <span class="inner">
    text
  </span>
  __
</div>
```